# Storing AIDL Callback Interface permanently

Tags: android, middleware, aidl

I'm trying to develop a middleware to which apps should be able to register when the app is opened for the first time. So I used one AIDL file to create an interface to connect with the middleware and another AIDL file as callback for the middleware to invoke the apps or send data to it. When an app registers with the middleware, it send the callback interface with the register request:

```
public void registerApplication(String id, String JSONSpecs, IMiddlewareCallbackInterface callback)
```

I want to store these callbacks permanently so that the middleware does not lose them when the running service or the phone is restarted. How do I accomplish that? If not using AIDL for callbacks, is there any alternatives that I can use for the same purpose?

Comment: You would need to re-establish these connections after a reboot. You cannot persist an AIDL interface.

Comment: Are there any alternatives to using AIDL callbacks to solve this problem?

Comment: If you have correctly read this page : https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html and you ended that AIDL it's the only/best way to handle your specific situation, no.

Comment: I do not know what the problem is. After all, neither your process nor those of your clients will be around forever. While a reboot scenario is clearly going to force you to deal with fresh processes, this will also happen many times per day, without a reboot. Any IPC that involves a durable connection (bound services, `Messenger`, etc.) needs to be able to re-establish that connection at any point when needed. If that is a problem, switch to IPC that does not involve a connection (e.g., broadcasts).